# Container is wrap the text widget but why the button widget get affected by the textAlign?

Tags: android, flutter

Sir, In code I am wrapping the only Text widget. After that I used some custom style like text align. But after use I expected to center only the text part because only this widget get wrapped not to the other. But I saw my button also get centered. How it possible? I was wrapped one widget but my other widget get affected. What's logic into there, sir?
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you please share your code ?

Comment: check out what are you using as the parent widget check out their alignments, if you face any problem add some code, so that it can be clear what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Set column widget's `mainaxisalignement` to start, or wrap all widget that you don't want to center in a column

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start`, and wrap the headline text with center widget. hope the below code can show you a good example.

```
class Demo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("title"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: Text("Whats your favourite food?"),
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text("Answer 1"),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text("Answer 1"),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text("Answer 1"),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```